# Is it possible to create a log for each process in a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How would I go about making a log section on my program or any program? I would like to see each process showing in the log with a time it happened. Below is a screen shot of another program I saw but I would like to include something similar in mine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a more academic answer, you could check out aspect-oriented programming, which is perfect for applications like logging. You can read more about its applications to logging [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Motivation_and_basic_concepts).